# Is the CnosDB-cli couldn't recognize the -p parameter?

Tags: database, cnosdb

I create a new user.

```
public ❯ SELECT *
FROM cluster_schema.users;
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_name | is_admin | user_options                                                                   |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| root      | true     | {"hash_password":"*****","must_change_password":true,"comment":"system admin"} |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Query took 0.038 seconds.
public ❯ CREATE
USER IF NOT EXISTS tester WITH PASSWORD='123';
Query took 0.867 seconds.
public ❯ SELECT *
FROM cluster_schema.users;
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_name | is_admin | user_options                                                                   |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| root      | true     | {"hash_password":"*****","must_change_password":true,"comment":"system admin"} |
| tester    | false    | {"hash_password":"*****"}                                                      |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Query took 0.018 seconds.
```

and I want to login in the user.

```
❯ ./target/debug/cnosdb-cli -u tester -p '123'
error: unrecognized subcommand '123'
```

it's strange that I cannot login normally.